# Image Bouncing while doing interface orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I am having paging in my application. Each page having Image. during the orientation i am changing the frame according to the landscape and portrait orientation. but image is bouncing. It should not bounce and want to set smoothly.

please let us know what can i do.

I am changing the frame in

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Here are some code.

```
 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
    {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            [self performSelector:@selector(setLandscapeOrientationFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:(duration/2)];
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSelector:@selector(setPortraitOrientationFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:(duration/2)];
        }

    }
```

And in "`setPortraitOrientationFrame`" and "`setLandscapeOrientationFrame`" I am changing frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working iOS6, you can use [autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2). The reason may be because you have used delay. If you use the code that follows, it may work.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {

     if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
     {
         [self setLandscapeOrientationFrame];
     }
     else
     {
         [self setPortraitOrientationFrame];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you working on `iOS6+`? If yes, then i recommend you to follow `autoLayout` feature of it. Go through [Beginning Auto Layout in iOS 6](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) step by step once and you will understand beauty of `autoLayout`. In `autoLayout` there is no need to set frame's positions manually in the code.